# Left join in codeigniter from two table and two values want to display

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

table 1 contain timing shedule, and table 2 contain name of category. I need category name and timing to show with id's from the two table with left join, how it possible?

Comment: db schema?. please provide full details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out below query

```
select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```

in CI

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2 ', 'table1.id=table2.id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code which will help to get the data from the two tables and getting the two values from both the tables:
<?PHP
 $this->db->select('t1.name, t2.desc')
 ->from('table_first as t1')
 ->where('t1.id', $id)
 ->join('table_second as t2', 't1.id = t2.id', 'LEFT')
 ->get();
?>
```